# Need Header slider plugin recommendation

Tags: plugins, plugin-recommendation, slideshow

i want the plugin to show  header image slider with pagination and the images are **capable to change threw the admin panel**.**integrating via theme**(template part) is very important.

I tried wp-nivo and nivo jquery slider but it doesn't support to change the images threw admin panel.

am diggingmy head for past 2 days.any one help me to get rid of this problem.

thanks in advance

Comment: **Please** - and that's very important to not clutter the site - **DO NOT** add tags that don't exist, until you have a **very good** reason!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [Wordpress Skitter Slideshow](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-skitter-slideshow/). It allows [setup of the slideshow images](http://s.wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-skitter-slideshow/screenshot-1.jpg) via the WP admin. You can only control *one* slideshow on your website.